# jaxrs - error throws in interceptor return status 500

Tags: java, authentication, jax-rs, httpresponse

I'm bulid rest api using jax-rs. To handle authentication I'm using Interceptor. When auth failed I return WebApplicationException like:

```
try
      {
         Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                 .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(policy.getUserName(), policy.getPassword()));
         SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
         securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
      catch (AuthenticationServiceException | BadCredentialsException e)
      {
         throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED); //TODO set response status
      }
```

but it returns startus 500 instead 401.

When i throw WebApplicationExceptions in services it return statuses that I set but in interceptor it didn't worked. How to return 401 from interceptor?

jaxrs:server config:

```
<jaxrs:server id="restService" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="securityInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="serviceBean" class="some_package.CustomerService"/>

<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="some_package.AuthenticatorInterceptor"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but possibly fo authentication you should use filters instead of interceptors.

Comment: @mkrakhin I tried with filters but I have jsr311-api in version 1.1.1 it didn't worked and I can't upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class Example implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: How about jersey version 1*

Answer (score 0):

Your interceptor is called before the JAX-RS resource is called, meaning that it doesn't know about the JAX-RS setup yet.

I would use an `ExceptionMapper` to convert to an appropriate response, regardless of where it gets thrown from.

Comment: I create Mapper with annotation @Provider, add config to xml, add to providers list of jaxrs:server but he doesn't fire when I throw exception.